# Упорядоченный списком рендеринг данных из localStorage

Tags: javascript, localstorage

Клик на Edit > ввод данных > клик на Save changes > обновить страницу. 
Результат должен быть: вывод на странице в списке тех данных, что я выводил до объявления страницы. 
Здесь песочница подглючивает. Видимо, не работает с localStorage. 
Ссылка на codepen: https://codepen.io/alexseveneight/pen/rqvZjG

```js
let out = document.getElementById('out');
let ul = document.createElement('ul');
out.appendChild(ul);

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  let li = document.createElement('li');
  ul.appendChild(li);
  li.setAttribute('contentEditable', false);
}

let button = document.getElementById('button');

button.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
  setTimeout(function(){
      let li = document.querySelectorAll('li');
  for(let i=0; i < li.length; i++) {
      if(li[i].contentEditable === 'false'){
        li[i].contentEditable = 'true';
        button.innerHTML = 'Save changes';
  }
  else {
    li[i].contentEditable = 'false';
    button.innerHTML = 'Edit';
    localStorage.setItem(li[i].innerHTML, li[i].innerHTML);
    localStorage.getItem(li[i].innerHTML, li[i].innerHTML);
    //localStorage.clear()
     }
     }
  },0);
}                       
)
```

```css
ul {
  height: 50px;
  //width: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
li {
  background-color: gray;
  border: 1px dotted #000;
  width: calc(100%/10);
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
button {
  padding: 5px 20px;
  border: 1px dotted green;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<button id="button">Edit</button>
<ul>
  <li>Customer</li>
  <li>Country FROM</li>
  <li>Postal code FROM</li>
  <li>Customs TO</li>
  <li>Delivery TO</li>
  <li>LDM - pallets</li>
  <li>Weight</li>
  <li>ADR</li>
  <li>Value of goods</li>
  <li>Price, EUR</li>
</ul>
<p id="out"></p>
```

Comment: легче все в 1 объект записать и потом его сериализовать и уже сохронять в localStorage и уже откуда брать и эту строку обравно в олект сериализовать

Comment: Нет возможности. Каждый раз создаётся новая строка с новыми данными. Будет много объектов, в таком случае. Неудобно.

Comment: не проблема.  тогда сохранатяь в таком виде   [ ваша строка №1 ]  сериализуете массив в строку  сохраняете в local помто если новая строка достате  из local  делаете массив добавляете строку и потмо снова  в local сохраняете

Comment: много действи но зато все в 1 месте

Comment: то есть что то такое превратится в такео JSON.stringify([ { name: 'awdwadawa', age : 34 }, { name: 'awdwadawa', age : 34 }]) результат 
"[{"name":"awdwadawa","age":34},{"name":"awdwadawa","age":34}]"